# I can't mine gold or diamond

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am in survival (No monster spawning.) I have a diamond pick axe and I still can't mine gold ore. I have already tried stone, wood and iron pickaxes.

Comment: are you absolutely sure your using a diamond pickaxe? the only reason I can think of for this to be happening is that you're wrong.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and the only way I fixed it was to completely delete the application from my iPhone. I do not know if this works for everyone, but if it is a big problem I would consider deleting it.

Answer (score -3):

Those blocks can only be mined with an iron or diamond pickaxe. Wood, stone and gold don't work.

Comment: Read the question carefully